# Hostname and IP address of the OS in the docker keep changing

Tags: docker, centos7

Using a blank centos7 image I start a container with `docker run -it centos:7.7.1908` 
I set the hostname at `/etc/hostname` and IP with hostname at `/etc/hosts` and make a few other changes.

At this point all looks good. I then open up another `shell` get the contain ID and do a docker commit, basically make a new image `foo` from the running container

When i then start a new container from the image foo `docker run -it foo` it has all the changes I made with the exception to the changed in the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`. They get reset to some random sting and IP address.

Why is this? Or is there a better way to set the IP and hostname in an image?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the IP address and hostname with --ip and --hostname, respectively when you create a new container with docker run.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am using Docker-Compose -> Dockerfile setup.
For reason that are a bit long winded to go into I need the hostname and IP address setup in the image before I start installing software on top and cannot change.

Comment: About the IP address, as I know, when you define a user-defined network and start containers in that network, each container gets an IP address starting from 172.21.0.2 and goes on. So you define an user-defined network, and predict what IP will be assigned to your container. 
About the hostname, I don't have anything in mind how to do that.